# Certificate handling: Difference between apache httpclient 4.0.1 and 4.1.2?

Tags: java, ssl, httpclient

I try to connect to a server that uses certificates. I call this code before connecting to make sure that all certificates are accepted. This works well using apache httpclient 4.0.1. But recently I updated to 4.1.2 and now I get the following error.

```
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class CertificateAcceptor {

    public void initializeTrustManager() {
        try {
            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            context.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
            System.out.println("Certificate");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
            new X509TrustManager() {
                   public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                       return null;
                   }

                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                        String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                        String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            }
            };


}
```

Nevertheless I always get this error message:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:397)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:573)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:425)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)..
...
```

What could be the reason for that?

Comment: The example about the `SSLContext` in your question clearly uses `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection` and isn't related to Apache HttpClient 4.0.1 or 4.1.2. What's the link? How did you set the `SSLContext` when Apache HttpClient?

Answer (score 2):

Apache HttpClient prior to version 4.1 used to pick up default SSL settings from `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection` by mistake. This is no longer the case as of version 4.1.

Please use HttpClient native API to configure SSL context for HTTPS connections.